# Use `ufw` to access localhost:port (mobile development)

Tags: 18.04, server, firewall, ufw, web-development

I was hoping to use `ufw` command to modify rules and allow connection over the wifi network to localhost8080 on my ubuntu 18.4 OS. Then I figured I'd be able to use the address (192.168.*.*:8080) to access my development server from my mobile phone.

Shouldn't that work?

tried using something like this: `sudo ufw allow from any to 192.168.*.* port 8080 proto tcp`

Comment: No, it wont. If you want to connect to your server to command line you need ssh server and a client. If you want to use port 8080 you need apache on your server but also a website to connect to. If you want to use the desktop you need VNC or something similar.

Comment: Okay, looks like setting up an aws server with ssh is probably the way to go then-- Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if `*` will work on `ufw`. Maybe should be better to use all subnet range using submask, like `192.168.1.0/24`

Sometimes when I develop in PHP and I want to **start built-in web server on the given local address and port**, I use `php -S <your_local_ip>:<port>` . Also maybe you need to specify which directory, so: `php -S <your_local_ip>:<port> -t <directory_to_serve>`

[image]

Then I use `ufw` to allow access from my mobile.

So, to enable access from another device of your subnetwork, commonly you should use the local IP of which who are serving, instead of using 'localhost', which usually redirects to 127.0.0.1:

[image]

---

This is how I do it.
I hope this serves for someone, someday.

Regards.